# How is cdkPortal different from ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-cdk

Why should one use [cdkPortal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview) over the built-in directives [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) and [ngComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) in Angular. aren't both of them provide the same functionality? Are there specific features in the CDK Portal that doesn't come with the built-in directives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the first example in the `cdkPortal` [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview), you will notice one big advantage/commodity:

`cdkPortalOutlet` **unifies** the functionality of `ngTemplateOutlet` and `ngComponentOutlet` by allowing devs. to embed both *templates* and *components* into the view dynamically.

Furthermore, `ComponentPortal` allows to dynamically pass `Injector` instances, which can become handy in cases where you need finer control over the dependency resolution of the to-be-embedded component.